# How to simplify in a single line FOR loop the multiplication of the numbers of a list?

Tags: python, for-loop, lambda

I want to get the result of multiplying all the numbers that are into a list, using a for loop written in a single line OR using a Lambda funtion

I've solved it easily using a classic for loop, but I want to simplify the expression. The idea is not to use libraries.

My current code:

```
num_list = [5,7,3,8]

R = 1;
for num in num_list:
    R *= num

print(R)
>>> 840
```

What I've tried:

```
R=1
R = [R*=num for num in num_list ]
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I expect to get the same value (=840) when simplify the expression

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this with [reduce](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functools.html) and [operator](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/operator.html):

```
from functools import reduce
import operator

num_list = [5,7,3,8]
reduce(operator.mul, num_list)
```

In **[Python 3.8](https://docs.python.org/3.8/whatsnew/3.8.html)** (to be released next year) see [here](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/math.html#math.prod):

> Added new function, math.prod(), as analogous function to sum() that
>   returns the product of a ‘start’ value (default: 1) times an iterable
>   of numbers. (Contributed by Pablo Galindo in bpo-35606)

so you will be able to do `math.prod(num_list)`